# Intellij Idea javascript formatting for multi-line var

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, formatting

So I've spent a significant amount of time trying to make the javascript code style Options in intellij do what I want and haven't found a solution.
If I have multple vars declared with comments like so

```
var obj = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 'three',
  value1: 'abc',
  // This is the comment about the. next var
  value3: 'four;
```

and I format the code I end up with

```
var obj = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 'three',
  value1: 'abc',
// This is the comment about the next var
  value3: 'four;
```

Is there anyway to keep that comment indention?  I see similar behavior on chained functions

```
angular.module('aModule', [])
  /**
   * This is a controller
   */
  .controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope = [1,2,3];
  });
```

format file

```
angular.module('aModule', [])
/**
 * This is a controller
 */
  .controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope = [1,2,3];
  });
```

I'm using intellij Idea 13. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Project Settings` - `Code Style` - `JavaScript` - `Wrapping and Braces` - check off `Comment at first column`

Comment: This is correct for multi-line variables.  There were some other formatting side effects, but was worth the update.  The second part with chained function has been identified as a bug in intellij and there is an open issue.  https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-13538